# Casting con método getText() Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Tags: java, javafx, casting

A la hora de crear un objeto tengo lo siguiente:

```
c1 = new Piso(Planta, Referencia, Precio, Superficie, Habitaciones);
```

Para recoger esos valores de Textos de campo he usado lo siguiente:

```
Planta = Integer.parseInt(TFPlanta.getText());                
Referencia = Integer.parseInt(TFReferencia.getText());
Habitaciones = Integer.parseInt(TFHabitaciones.getText());
Precio = Double.valueOf(TFPrecio.getText());
Superficie = Double.valueOf(TFSuperficie.getText());
Parcela = Double.valueOf(TFParcela.getText());
Planta1 = Double.valueOf(TFPlanta1.getText());
Planta2 = Double.valueOf(TFPlanta2.getText());
```

Haciendo esto no consigo obtener los valores de los campos, mientras que si en vez de usar el `getText()` incluyo valores manuales sí puedo crear el objeto perfectamente:

```
Planta = Integer.parseInt("421");                
Referencia = Integer.parseInt("231");
Habitaciones = Integer.parseInt("323");
Precio = Double.valueOf("4312");
Superficie = Double.valueOf("5123");
Parcela = Double.valueOf("6321");
Planta1 = Double.valueOf("7123");
Planta2 = Double.valueOf("3218");
```

¿Por qué me podría fallar esto? También he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
String Planta0 = TFPlanta.getText();
int Planta = Integer.parseInt(Planta0);
```

El error que me muestra es al pulsar el boton de Añadir (La aplicación se ejecuta correctamente pero falla ahí) y muestra lo siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at gestioninmobiliaria.FXMLDocumentController.registrarVivienda(FXMLDocumentController.java:196)
    ... 62 more
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Te está dando un error muy claro: NumberFormatException: empty String. Las funciones getText te están retornando una cadena vacía. O bien no hay nada que leer en los EditText o es que estás intentando leer otros EditText. Y te está dando en un double, así que parece que los enteros que hay antes sí los convierte bien.

Answer (score 1):

prueba a poner

```
Integer.parseInt(TFPlanta.getText().toString());
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: --> empty String <--
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at -->java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538) <--
    at gestioninmobiliaria.FXMLDocumentController.registrarVivienda(FXMLDocumentController.java:196)
    ... 62 more
```

Si te fijas en la excepción, te está diciendo que en la línea 538 de tu código, estas llamando al método parseDouble y que le estás pasando como parámetro una cadena vacía.

Antes de utilizar los parser, comprueba que los diferentes campos que pasas como parámetros, tengan valor.

Answer (score 0):

teníais razón, el String estaba vacío y no había nada para convertir, finalmente lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma:

```
if (TFPlanta.getText().isEmpty()){
    TFPlanta.setText("0");
    Planta = Integer.parseInt(TFPlanta.getText());
} else {
    Planta = Integer.parseInt(TFPlanta.getText());                    
}
```

He comprobado si estaba vacía le asignara el valor 0 y luego la convierta a Integer o Double
Muchas gracias a todos.